# AWS lambda policy to invoke another lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, policy

I need to invoke the lambda `function2` from lambda `function1` using aws sdk.

So far I have the following policy on `function1`

```
        {
            "Sid": "AllowToInvokeLambda",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:XXX:function:function2"
        },
```

But it fails with  `AccessDeniedException: status code: 403`

Comment: Where did you attach the above policy to?

Comment: @jellycsc Attach it to the `function1`, in permissions section, modifying json

Comment: Can show the code?

Comment: I've already shown it. Nothing else to share really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to double-check again your **Lambda Permissions** with *Execution Role* as below.

[image: lambda-execution-role]

Ensure that it has the permission to **invoke** other Lambda functions. Here is a simple policy I use:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

To test this, I have a simple code here:

```
    client = boto3.client('lambda')

    response = client.invoke(
        FunctionName='invoke-test-2',
        InvocationType='Event',
        Payload='{}',
    )
    
    print(response)
```

Here is the result:
[image: lambda-invoke-another-lambda-response]

Comment: Oh, thank you, at the same time we've found typo in code invoking the lambda